# AndroidViewClient and Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, python, emulation, genymotion

I am setting Genymotion Android emulators and AndroidViewClient to test my app. Is AndroidViewClient able to connect to the Genymotion android emulator ?
Thanks

Comment: I open the Genymotion emulator and run the command culebra -i false -d true -r -j true as a test but get this error message : 
    raise ValueError("Regular expression not supported as serialno in ViewClient. Found '%s'" % serialno)
ValueError: Regular expression not supported as serialno in ViewClient. Found '* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *'
It looks like AndroidViewClient can not connect to Genymotion emulator, any idea how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion behaves like a USB connected device so it should definitely be compatible with AndroidViewClient.

You need first to configure Genymotion to make it use your [ADB binary from your Android SDK](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=adb-connection#faq):

> 1. Open Genymotion > Settings > ADB
> 2. Check Use custom Android SDK tools
> 3. Specify the path to the Android SDK by clicking Browse
> 4. Click OK.

After that, you should find your Genymotion instances inside your ADB deamon. Open a command line and type: `adb devices`

You should get as a result, like this:

```
List of devices attached 
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

The "ip:port device" line is your Genymotion machine running.

At this moment, you can run AndroidViewClient tool.

Comment: I change the adb settings in Genymotion but the error message still exists. Even without changing adb to Android sdk in Genymotion, I execute the command adb devices (adb from android sdk) and the results already displays 192.168.56.100:5555, so adb can see the Genymotion mulator but not AndroidViewClient

Comment: I use the command culebra -G --serialno=192.168.56.100:5555 and AndroidclientView/Culebra looks to connect to the Genymotion emulator but still generates an error message : ...File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 341, in __init__
    if self.isScrollable():
  File "C:\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 377, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, name
AttributeError: isScrollable

Comment: AndroidViewClient can connect to Genymotion emulators but the serialno should be set like "IP:PORT" which is the Genymotion emulator when it runs, but I think culebra -G (GUI mode with Pillow installed) stilll has some bugs.